# Array error in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[][][] inputs;

inputs = new int[10][][];

inputs[0] = new int[1][];
inputs[0][0] = new int[14]{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1};
```

This is an excerpt from my program, I have no idea why this is causing an error. Isn't this correct?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Did you **read** the error message? At least in Eclipse it's *pretty clear*. And even if you don't *understand it*, you should at least *post it in your question*!

Comment: Having tried it, I have to say that the error message from `javac` is way more cryptic: `error: ';' expected`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Eclipse I get a pretty clear error message:

> Cannot define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided.

That means that you can *either* specify the dimension *or* the array initializer (i.e. the values). You **can't** specify both at the same time.

Simply change your last line to

```
inputs[0][0] = new int[]{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1};
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot construct an array with a declared length AND a static initialiser.  It must be either one or the other.

change `inputs[0][0] = new int[14]{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1};` to `inputs[0][0] = new int[]{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1};` - the length of the new array is implicit because you are explicitly initialising the array with 14 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The last line should simply be:

```
inputs[0][0] = {1,1, etc.};
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. You *need* the `new int[]` *unless* it's an initializer (and this is simply an assignment).